# how to get id from user authenticated in application spring boot using keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm new to working with Spring Security and would like to know how to access authenticated user information.

I tried to use `SecurityPrincipal` but through it I can only get the `username`, I would like to get `email`, `id` and other attributes that come in the token.

**How can I get the user id and other attributes that comes in the `accessToken`?**

Comment: I'm curious, why didn't the post below help or even answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Details depends on your configuration, but token claims should be in the `Authentication` instance stored in the security context. You can access it:

- statically with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`
- as method argument to your `@Controllers`: `@GetMapping("/greet") public MessageDto getGreeting(Authentication auth) { ... }`

I have written [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for various ways to configure Spring applications with OAuth2. All of those tutorials work with Keycloak.